# Литература по нейронным сетям и ИИ

Tags: книги, нейронные-сети

Посоветуйте хорошую литературу по теме. Хотелось бы почитать то, что считается классикой в этой области. Возможно есть хорошие научные статьи, которые позволяют быстро понять текущее состояние дел или очертить текущий край достижений. Язык английский/русский.
Понимаю, что вопрос банальный, но все же хотелось бы услышать специалистов в этой области.

Answer (score 1):

Bishop. Neural Networks for Pattern Recognition

Answer (score 0):

Литературы не посоветую, но есть цикл на хабре: [Логика мышления. Часть 1. Нейрон](http://habrahabr.ru/post/214109/).
Сам еще не читал, но народ хвалит.
Ну и внизу топика есть ссылки =)